# Workbox doesn't match anything

Tags: workbox

Here the generated code

```
importScripts("https://storage.googleapis.com/workbox-cdn/releases/4.3.1/workbox-sw.js");

workbox.setConfig({
  debug: true
});

workbox.precaching.precacheAndRoute([
  {
    "url": "/rest/resource/build.all.json",
    "revision": "9d178a1ffe18be2bce92e19fe306416d"
  },
  {
    "url": "/rest/resource/build.development.css",
    "revision": "5ab54583dfad8742646fb861508fcc35"
  },
  {
    "url": "/rest/resource/build.development.js",
    "revision": "7a1e8c3842995311ff261d4c61019b9a"
  },
  {
    "url": "/rest/resource/build.en.json",
    "revision": "3d61d4813aee32b2923d641a31315038"
  },
  {
    "url": "/rest/resource/build.es.json",
    "revision": "0156fc3e3ce19ce1599637297a1e2c34"
  },
  {
    "url": "/rest/resource/build.production.css",
    "revision": "d735af4146c40622a86fa4fb0f98a189"
  },
  {
    "url": "/rest/resource/build.production.js",
    "revision": "66ff9441978be021d9266c85d2dcdf5f"
  },
  {
    "url": "/rest/resource/cache-worker.development.js",
    "revision": "7bb4f72279b7dcabed44bc64aeb8c31f"
  },
  {
    "url": "/rest/resource/cache-worker.production.js",
    "revision": "85dc9271fa5116b22427bec55a363ed1"
  },
  {
    "url": "/rest/resource/es.moment.js",
    "revision": "0c22f2804c5531dcffd6645db0c29f3d"
  },
  {
    "url": "index.html",
    "revision": "ecc5d5effdf0bed580f7f690dbb1659e"
  },
  {
    "url": "/rest/resource/lang.json",
    "revision": "d03767404afe4cfb994f4a968d3dbdb9"
  },
  {
    "url": "/rest/resource/terms_and_conditions/en.html",
    "revision": "3c5e6f698cc4b73027fb376ee5c681c9"
  },
  {
    "url": "/rest/resource/terms_and_conditions/es.html",
    "revision": "6c22a15d10216f293b0658417b7a1b9a"
  }
],
  {
    // Ignore all URL parameters.
    ignoreURLParametersMatching: [/.*/],
  },
);

workbox.routing.registerNavigationRoute(
  workbox.precaching.getCacheKeyForURL('index.html'), {
    blacklist: [
      new RegExp('/rest/uploads/'),
      new RegExp('/rest/util/'),
      new RegExp('/rest/autocomplete/'),
      new RegExp('/rest/autocomplete-check/'),
      new RegExp('/rest/index-check/'),
      new RegExp('/graphql/'),
    ],
  }
);
```

I can see the cache being generated and the files being stored there properly in the cache.

After that workbox stops doing anything and won't even match a file ever.

I'd expect that every time at least my server calls to fetch the /rest/resources/build.en.json files, workbox would actually return the files, but that never happens, workbox doesn't even log messages anymore, doesn't check, it just remains silent.

It would never match index either, this is a SPA and what is not a url resource and what is not in the specified folders should serve index, but that doesn't do anything either.

Answer (score 1):

After switching to normal service workers (Without workbox) I managed to figure it out as it was the scope of the worker not taking into consideration the root directory as it was in a subfolder.

Basically the worker was in `dist/worker.js` and not in `worker.js` which means the fetch event wasn't triggering for `/resources`

I will remain using the normal workers as they are easier to debug nevertheless, but for those that might have a similar issue, this can become a reference.

Comment: This is useful. I placed service worker file in a deeply nested directory to organise it well and spent hours debugging the issue. Always put service worker file in the root of your site